# Highcharts data grouping on mixed data

Tags: highcharts

I've prepared a highstock chart with mixed stock data that includes:

- nearly 4000 daily points (one per day)
- 2500 intraday points (one point every 15 minutes) for the last month
- 6000 points (every few seconds) for the current date

Such a scenario let you see the historical data as well as zoom in into detailed recent data.

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/6rwbs3cj/3/ and it has the following plotOptions and dataGrouping

```
plotOptions: {
  ohlc: {
    turboThreshold: 0,
    color: '#00cc00',
    upColor: 'red'
  },
  series: {
    dataGrouping: {
      units: [
        [
          'second',
          [1]
        ],
        [
          'minute',
          [1, 5, 15]
        ],
        [
          'hour',
          [1, 4]
        ],
        [
          'day',
          [1]
        ],
        [
          'week',
          [1]
        ],
        [
          'month',
          [1, 3, 6]
        ],
        [
          'year',
          null
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

Once opened it uses 4h grouping it looks very squashed.

[image]

If by using navigator I take out a bit of the current data it changes the grouping to monthly grouping and the chart becomes readable.
[image]

Similar happens if I uses 1-year Zoom (1y button in rangeSelector) - on the last 12 month of the data it uses 5 minutes data grouping and it is very squashed.
[image]

After moving a bit left on the navigator (taking out some of the recent data) the automated grouping becomes 1h
[image]

Moving a bit more left on the navigator changes grouping to daily
[image]

Is there a way to make automated data grouping looking at the overall data rather then the most detailed part of the data?

Comment: It appears that the method of data entry is not working quite correctly, and the data is being misinterpreted as of 29 December 2022.

Comment: I recreated this grouping in another [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3cbt6pko/) and didn't observe a problem with squashed data, could you check this?

Comment: @SebastianHajdus - on your sample it hasn't happened because it only had daily data (one point per day). I've modified your example: https://jsfiddle.net/5jw6bh93/ I've added additional dataGrouping units (1,5,15 minutes, 1,4 hours, 1 day) and additional 300 points every 5 seconds and it was still ok but when I added 300 more points (so 600 points in total) the error occurred again.

Answer (score 0):

When [dataGrouping.forced](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.ohlc.dataGrouping.forced) is on, no matter how small the interval is, it will automatically adjust the distance between points.

It's also possible to set [dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.ohlc.dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth) approximate pixel width.

```
  dataGrouping: {
    forced: true,
    groupPixelWidth: 50,
  }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7ofp4wza/)

Comment: IMO in the demo above grouping still isn't correct. The data prior to 23Dec2022 is still squashed. If you select "1Y" you get 5min grouping and the data prior to 23Dec2022 is still squashed, scrolling with navigator to the left to period of Dec2021-Dec2022 changes grouping from 5min to weekly. I've noticed that with data up to 1672248840000 initial grouping is 5min, but having the data up to 1672248835000 changes the initial grouping to weekly. If one additional point makes a difference so it might be connected to amount of daily data (prior to 23Dec2022) vs amount of intraday data (28Dec2022)

Comment: For example, if you set the dataGrouping to `units: [['minute',[5]]]`, the data are grouped in this way permanently, otherwise if you have, for example, in `units: [['minute',[5, 10, 15]]]` the data are automatically calculated and chose the best according to the data. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7ofp4wza/3/)